# Как в Python результат Javascript сохранить в переменную

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

Друзья, очень нужна ваша помощь. Используя Python и JS в Jupyter столкнулся с очень большое (для меня) проблемой:

Как сохранить результат работы JS в переменную, а не отображать ее в Out[...]

Пример кода:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import HTML

js_test = """
var a = 2;
var b= 2;
var c = a+b;
element.text(c);
"""
Res=Javascript(js_test)
```

Мне надо преобразовать Res в переменную и получить "4". Если Res просто присвоить другой переменной, то я получаю "IPython.core.display.Javascript"

Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Прямо очень-очень!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30537286/5741205

Comment: MaxU, ЗАРАБОТАЛО. Вообще огромное спасибо что быстро ответили.

Comment: Другим может пригодится ваше решение, если вы оформите его как ответ и укажете в нем код ;)

Comment: @MaxU, за ответ спасибо! Я конечно покажу в ответе фрагмент кода, который успешно отработал. Но очень хочется сделать код более гибким. Например, будет интересно как из моего примера получить данные переменной "Res" без функции display? Если так можно, то пример станет более универсальным в использовании.